# Jquery/Bootstrap DataTable Sorting not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

```
 $('#StudentTable').dataTable({

    "aaSorting": [],
    "bSorting": false,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bDestroy": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "sScrollY": "224px",
    "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "StudentId" },
                    { "sTitle": "Name" },
                    { "sTitle": "Address" },
                    { "sTitle": "Mobileno" },
                    { "sTitle": "Email" }
                ],

    "aaData": Students
});
```

I am binding data to datatable dynamically...but problem is sorting not working properly.. it will sort Studentid 1 to 10 properly but if it is gretter then 10 it will come some studentid in top .you can see bellow  output of sorting

[image: See output of sorting order]

Comment: Yes - Perhaps this is treated as string and sorting like string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell dataTable what kind of datatype each column exist of. Set the StudentId sType to "sType": 'numeric' and it should sort correct.

```
$('#StudentTable').dataTable({

"aaSorting": [],
"bSorting": false,
"bProcessing": false,
"bPaginate": false,
"bFilter": false,
"bDestroy": false,
"bAutoWidth": true,
"sScrollY": "224px",
"aoColumns": [
                { "sTitle": "StudentId", "sType": 'numeric'  },
                { "sTitle": "Name" },
                { "sTitle": "Address" },
                { "sTitle": "Mobileno" },
                { "sTitle": "Email" }
            ],

"aaData": Students
```

});

Comment: if it is numeric concatenated with string.which data type need to use

Comment: If your column dont follow regular datatypes you should implement a custom sort order function. Se this page for more info. http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting